# FragmentStateAdapter createFragment - when do you actually need to create new fragments/when do fragments get deleted?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager2, fragmentstateadapter

I have been learning how to use FragmentStateAdapter and ViewPager2, and one of the issues I'm encountering is the logic behind what to do in `createFragment`.  I know a fragment must be returned, but some sample apps have a list of fragments passed to the adapter and do something like:

```
override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    fragmentList[postion]
}
```

While other samples create the fragments in the method like:

```
    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return FragmentOne()
            1 -> return FragmentTwo()
            2 -> return FragmentThree()
        }
        // ...
    }
```

I feel that the second option is safer and I wanted to prove that it would be bad to do the first approach, but I've been unable to see any bad behavior/issues when using the first option.  I've gone to the extreme and setup a view pager to use 100 fragments and an `offscreenPageLimit` value set to 1, for example!  In these cases, fragment views *are* being re-created more often, but `createFragment` is never called when viewing older fragments that have been swiped past before.

Am I missing something simple here? When do fragments need to be re-created?

Comment: I found that I can get the method to be called again when using a view pager with 100 fragments, scrolling to position 10 or so, and then doing a garbage collection via Android Studio profiler, but it doesn't act bad/break/crash/etc. when re-using a fragment from the passed in fragmentlist - the value there is still valid/alive, so I'm still not sure what is best practice here.